# Yocto - How do I add a layer to my image using bbapend?

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I am a beginner in Yocto, and I have created an image in my build folder using

```
bitbake-layer create-layer meta-helloworld
```

Inside my Helloworld folder I have the recipe (.bb) file and the C source code to a helloworld program.
After succesfully bitbaking my Layer, I have added it to the image by editing local.conf adding the following line:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " helloworld"
```

This worked perfectly on the board. (I was able to run the helloworld program from the board's terminal)

However, as it's pointed in challinan's answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22846384/hello-world-bitbake-recipe-not-installed-in-image), this is not the best practice, and I should do it by adding a bbappend file in my layer, and according to the answer in the same question, add the dependencies in this file. I am however not aware of what these dependencies are nor how should I write them. I looked on the metadata and found some bbappend files but none of them provided anything very insightful.

**How do I add a custom layer to image using bbapend file?**

Further information: I am developping on a iMX6 board, using NXP sources but with a custom kernel. I am using devtool to change the kernel, but my custom layer recipe is outside the devtool (workspace) folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your image directory where your image.bb is present. e.g.

```
recipe-images/core-image-minimal.bbb

$ cd recipe-images
$ nano core-image-minimal.bbappend
```

Add the following line to your empty new file

```
 IMAGE_INSTALL += " helloworld"
```

Comment: I had accepted this answer but now I realise that it actually doesn't work. I've added the bbappend file just like you said, however when the image boots I can see that my layers/recipes have not been installed.

Comment: ok then try IMAGE_INSTALL_append = ” helloworld ” instead of IMAGE_INSTALL

Comment: and are you creating bbappend file of the image you are using? it should work.

Comment: I found the error. My layers.conf in poky was not looking for bbappend files. Now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to know is you are using using bbappend to add the layer, bbappend is used to extend/modify the existing recipe.

Steps to create and add custom layer to yocto environment:

```
$ bitbake-layer create-layer meta-helloworld
```

to add layer there are two ways -

1. Manually add the layer name with path in bblayer.conf file
2. By using bitbake command

   $ bitbake-layer add-layer meta-helloworld

You can get better idea here
[Add my own custom layer and create my own image in yocto](https://github.com/prashantdivate/meta-sirius)